# Search data in file using python, but searching the data by name

Tags: python, file, search

I have file **form.txt** I want to search a data in file just using by name, so if I wrote a name the data in file by the name will show up. Anyone know how to do it?. I'm newbie at this python and don't know how to do it, thanks by the way!!

**form.txt:**

> Farhan Hermansyah,Male,Moscow,25 December 2002, Christian, Russian,Not
> Married, High School, Parung Permata Indah, 08123123123,
> russian1sd4b3st@gmail.com, CEO
>
> Tedy,Male,Japan, 21 Februari 1990, Jewish, Indonesian, Married, P.Hd, Grovesttreet, 1231123,imhandsome@gmail.com, General Manager

```
code.py
def search(name) :
name = input("Enter The Name You Want To Look :")
f = open("form.txt", "r")
for name in f :
         print(readlines[0]
```

Comment: Maybe you need to be clear so that people can understand

Comment: Show your expected output and how you expect it and show what you've tried first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think you are looking for this:

```
name = input()
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if name == line.split(',')[0]:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# read txt file 
filetxt = open("s.txt")

data = filetxt.readlines()

def searchName(name,text):
    index = text.find(name)
    if (index >=0):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


for i in data:
    if (searchName("Tedy",i)):
        print(i)
    else:
        pass
```

this code should work when your data is like in example above.